# Throwing an exception from main class?

Tags: java, exception

In my code i surround the object instantiations in a try catch block because they throw an error, i instantiate many objects so my code looks very messy. I was wondering if it is okay to throw the exception from my main class, or is this bad practice?

Comment: Could you include your code here, for reference?

Comment: What will handle the exception thrown by your main method?

Comment: If this is just something small, it's probably okay. If this is something more involved with multiple inputs from the user for example, you might want to handle differently.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/257178/139941). Long story short, if you aren't handling the exception in a special way (you only care for the stacktrace if thrown), feel free to have the main method throw the exception

Comment: @BilltheLizard Exceptions that are thrown by the main method are handled by the (Thread)UncaughtExceptionHandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to throw exceptions from your entry-point (in this case, your `main` method), unless you can think of a specific reason not to ("the user shouldn't see that", "it would be better if I tried to recover, rather than exiting").

If you can handle the exceptions where they are, you should do so. For example, you could log them, re-throw them as more understandable exceptions (such as validation exceptions), or fail out of the method by returning null. If it doesn't make sense to handle them, then don't.

What you probably need is a nicer grouping of similar exceptions. You can move all of your code that's inside those try-catch blocks into a private method (perhaps `init`), which throws all the relevant exceptions. Then, call `init` from the `main` method, and wrap that `init` call in a try-catch block that catches all those exceptions.

Comment: "The user shouldn't see that" This made me delete my answer. I personally believe exceptions should be logged, rather than shown to the user. If anything, the user should be given an error message, rather than the full stack trace, informing the user they should submit their "error reports". +1